# Sending emails to friends from facebook application

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I want to invite friends via facebook to my application. For example user can send his friends facebook IDs to my php service, and this service send them emails via facebook api. I found notifications.sendEmail function for that, but it send email only for me if I logged in FB. So, can I send invitation emails by FB api if they are not users of my application?

Comment: In addition to what @DMCS answered below, I would also like to say that it is a **very bad idea** to use old and depricated methods...  Keep upto date with the changes facebook makes to their systems on their [Blog](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/) and the [Developers Roadmap](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sending app requests, please use https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/ as it is against policy for an app to automatically send app request to friends of its users. It must be user initiated and also user driven as to which friends get invited.

Also, you cannot get email addresses of a user's friends, this is also prohibited.